# Host SilverLight / WCF

Tags: wcf, silverlight-2.0

I have created my first silverlight app :-)

It has a basic page and connects to a db to populate a list. the connection is done using wcf, so my silverlight connects to a ServiceReference that does the stuff.
This all works fine when i run from VisualStudio.

My problem is that i am not sure how to host this app. 
I created an account on aspspider uploaded my default.html, zap file(which i renamed to zip), and Database. this work fine until it needs to connect to the db.
What do i need to upload to get the database connection working ?

Thanks :-)
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Can you connect to your WCF service through the browser or Fiddler?  Try taking Silverlight out of the equation and make sure your getting data from WCF.

In addition I noticed in your question that you don't mention anything about hosting your WCF service with aspspider.  Where are you hosting your WCF service?  As you first project you should setup the WCF service on the same domain as the silverlight app.  Otherwise you will have to get into using Silverlight Cross Domain policies theres a [video on silverlight.net](http://silverlight.net/learn/learnvideo.aspx?video=47174)

Answer (score 0):

I possibly sounded more knowledgeable than i am in my first post :-)
I don’t know how to host the wcf or even if it is truly wcf. 
I will try to explain where i am up to and would be really grateful if you could help!

In my solution i have a silverlight project which when i created i was prompted to add a webserver, which i did. when it came to adding db connection i did this by adding a "linq To sql classes" and a Webservice. So now in my webserver project i have a Iservice1.cs Service1.svc LinqToSql.dbml. 
I then added a reference in the silverlight.

Any ideas how i go about hosting this service ??

Thanks so much
Martin